# How can I show only values ​with all values in whereIn?

Tags: php, laravel

Now it will show post_id with tags 85 or 86 or 87.

How can I show only post_id with tags 85 and 86 and 87?

```
                           $values = DB::table('post_tag')
                                ->whereIn('tag_id', [85, 86, 87])
                                ->pluck('post_id');
```

This is the table structure

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this below

```
$values = DB::table('post_tag')
             ->where('tag_id', 85)
             ->where('tag_id', 86)
             ->where('tag_id', 87)
             ->pluck('post_id');
```

Comment: I tried it, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Add toArray() at the end of your query

```
$values = DB::table('post_tag')->whereIn('tag_id', [85, 86, 87])->pluck('post_id')->toArray();
```

Comment: it doesn't work

Comment: I have tested this before posting. What laravel version you are working on

Comment: laravel version 5.8

Answer (score 0):

you should add groupBy('post_id')

```
$values = DB::table('post_tag')->whereIn('tag_id', [85, 86, 87])->groupBy('post_id')->pluck('post_id')->toArray();
```

Comment: it doesn't work on laravel version 5.8

Comment: can you show me result of query?

Answer (score 0):

How can I show only values ​with all values in `whereIn()`? It is working fine in my project.

```
$users = User::whereIn('id',[12,13,14])->pluck('id')->toArray();
dd($users);
```

**Output**

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => 12
  1 => 13
  2 => 14
]
```